# Hibernate Batch Processing Using Native SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, batch-processing

I have an application using hibernate. One of its modules calls a native SQL (StoredProc) in batch process. Roughly what it does is that every time it writes a file it updates a field in the database. Right now I am not sure how many files would need to be written as it is dependent on the number of transactions per day so it could be zero to a million.

If I use this code snippet in while loop will I have any problems?

```
@Transactional
public void test()
{
  //The for loop represents a list of records that needs to be processed.
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
   {

   //Process the records and write the information into a file.
   ...

   //Update a field(s) in the database using a stored procedure based on the processed information. 
   updateField(String.valueOf(i));


   }
}

@Transactional(propagation=propagation.MANDATORY)    
public void updateField(String value)
{ 

Session session = getSession();

SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("exec spUpdate :value");

sqlQuery.setParameter("value", value);

sqlQuery.executeUpdate();

}
```

Will I need any other configurations for my data source and transaction manager?

Will I need to set hibernate.jdbc.batch_size and hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache?

Will I need to use session flush and clear for this? The samples in the hibernate tutorial is using POJO's and not native sql so I am not sure if it is also applicable.

Please note another part of the application is already using hibernate so as much as possible I would like to stick to using hibernate.

Thank you for your time and I am hoping for your quick response. If it is also possible could code snippet would really be useful for me.

---

Application Work Flow

1) Query Database for the transaction information. (Transaction date, Type of account, currency, etc..)

2) For each account process transaction information. (Discounts, Current Balance, etc..)

3)  Write the transaction information and processed  information to a file.

4) **Update a database field based on the process information**

5) Go back to step 2 while their are still accounts. (Assuming that no exception are thrown)

Comment: Bump!! Anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: Bump! Can anyone answer the question about the batch size, second level caching, session flush/clear please!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet will open and close the session for each iteration, which definitely not a good practice.

Is it possible, you have a job which checks how many new files added in the folder?

The job should run say every 15/25 minutes, checking how much files are changed/added in last 15/25 minutes and updates the database in batch.

Something like that will lower down the number of open/close session connections. It should be much faster than this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I updated my question to show a better representation of my application. Besides from what you suggested, will I need to do any other changes such as configurations to the transaction manager, session flushing/clearing, etc.. Thanks again for the help

Comment: If you are using Hibernate with Spring JDBC, then spring supports declarative transaction mgmt. 
Where you can define,
1. Transaction manager, with which methods u want to have transaction.
2. `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`, targeting your DAO class

So, You will actually use the bean of `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` instead of your own DAO. And that will be creating a proxy around your DAO. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks again for your reply. Sorry If my question to you was not clear. Actually what I am asking if I still need to add additional configurations to hibernate if transaction manager like the **hibernate.jdbc.batch_size** and disable the **hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache**. Also do I need to use the flush and clear methods while updating. Like what is shown here [http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html] as the tutorial only shows pojos im not sure if it applies to native sql. Thanks for your time...